# Как изменить стиль элементов в C# forms?

Tags: c#, winforms

Подскажите где и как изменить цвет вот этих элементов в Visual Studio ?
Элемент listView.
[image: Стиль c# forms]

Comment: Уточните для начала, что это за контролы?

Comment: это элемент listView

Answer (score 1):

Нужно включить свойство `OwnerDraw`, подписаться на событие отрисовки заголовка и в нем рисовать желаемым цветом:

```
listView1.OwnerDraw = true;
listView1.DrawColumnHeader += new DrawListViewColumnHeaderEventHandler(listView1_DrawColumnHeader);

...

private void listView1_DrawColumnHeader(object sender, DrawListViewColumnHeaderEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Red, e.Bounds);
    e.DrawText();
}
```

Также нужно подписаться на события отрисовки записи и подзаписи и сообщить, чтобы отрисовкой занималась ОС (иначе придется рисовать самому):

```
listView1.DrawItem += new DrawListViewItemEventHandler(listView1_DrawItem);
listView1.DrawSubItem += new DrawListViewSubItemEventHandler(listView1_DrawSubItem);

...

private void listView1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    e.DrawDefault = true;
}

private void listView1_DrawSubItem(object sender, DrawListViewSubItemEventArgs e)
{
    e.DrawDefault = true;
}
```

Подробный пример есть в [документации MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.ownerdraw.aspx) к свойству `OwnerDraw`.

UPD. Смена цвета линий таблицы стандартным API контрола не поддерживается. Есть пример кастомного контрола [на английском SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18283781/changing-listview-header-and-grid-lines-colors).

Comment: Получился чёрный цвет шапки и больше никаким цветом, а линии совсем не могу понять как красить.
Могу сделать решённым вопрос, но хотелось бы понять как нормально покрасить определённый элемент линию или шапку.

Comment: @Владимир хм, у меня цвет заголовков меняется без проблем. По поводу цвета линий -- обновил ответ.